# How to write FQL to fetch news feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have to fetch all data which is on News Feeds (public wall). What query should I write ?
I wrote `"SELECT likes,message FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  limit 50 "` query but it is returning my wall value. I want to fetch all data which is on my wall as well as on public (News Feed).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to expand that query with a subquery, to include items where the source_id is also from friends and pages that the user has "Liked". Does that sound like what you're after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `filter_key` to select the type of feed to use. The type you are after would probably be `newsfeed`, so the query could be something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')
```

For more information, have a look at the [stream_filter docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/).

Comment: works for me.. updated slighly as per example on facebook site, see in action on the graph explorer here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20post_id%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20in%20(SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20type%3D'newsfeed')%20AND%20is_hidden%20%3D%200

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it without querying FQL? :)

Use the Graph API instead:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...
```

Try it on using "Graph API Explorer". [/me/home](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me/home)