# How I can Retrive News Feed using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, feed, facebook-feed

I am working on WPF app and I want to get news feed using FQL so that I have the appID and Token I am new to this so can anybody help me how I can get this news feed in facebook..

Thank you..!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this type of fql query:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE 
filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')
```

See this links also:

1. [How to write FQL to fetch news feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570264/how-to-write-fql-to-fetch-news-feeds)
2. [How to get only photos from user's Facebook newsfeed using graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542841/how-to-get-only-photos-from-users-facebook-newsfeed-using-graph-api)

Update:

To read the [stream table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) you need:

1. **read_stream permissions** for all posts that the current session user is able to view
2. **read_insights permissions** to see post impressions for any posts made by a Page owned by the current session user

To read the [stream_filter table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/) you need:

1. **a valid access token** with basic permissions
2. **read_stream permissions** if used in combination with stream table).

Comment: That gives an error: "(#606) Queries for these filter_keys: \"nf\" require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission"

Comment: This doesn't work. Returns following error:
`"error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }`

Comment: Try this: ... SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed'

Comment: @Lücks: see update. do you have permissions taken from user for that?