# How to get only photos from user's Facebook newsfeed using graph api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I combed through the Facebook documentation but didn't see an obvious way to return ONLY photos on a user's newsfeed.  Specifically:

Give a FB access token, I want to get the newsfeed filtered to only photos that were posted.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=

Returns the entire newsfeed.  I see that elements have a "Type" attribute, that has a value of "photo" when it's a photo.

How can I scope the response to only return photos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can do this using FQL:

```
SELECT 
    post_id, message, attachment 
FROM 
    stream 
WHERE 
    filter_key 
IN (
    SELECT 
        filter_key 
    FROM 
        stream_filter 
    WHERE 
        uid = me() 
    AND 
        name = "Photos"
   )
```

Working demo using Graph API Explorer:
`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20post_id%2C%20message%2C%20attachment%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20filter_key%20IN%20(SELECT%20filter_key%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20name%3D%22Photos%22)`

**EDIT:**

Looks like that link won't work. This is the request to the graph api. You need `read_stream` permissions.

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND name="Photos")`

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how I can also filter out photos posted by "pages"? I only want to get photos posted by an actual friend vs. a business.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has added a filter parameter to the `/me/home endpoint` so if you query `/me/home?filter=photos` you get only photos from the users `News Feed`

Comment: Great discovery ! Where on earth are such good docs ? PS any way to get those thumbnails in a single query as well ? Cause otherwise the picture this will return is tiny

Comment: @AbhishekHingnikar in [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/home) it says pass a valid `filter_key` from the users `stream_filter` table. But `photos` is not present in that table but the key for the Photos app also works. Hoping to get some clarity on this from the Facebook team